# bitmask + typecasting does not return as expected

Tags: c, type-conversion, bit-manipulation

I have an situation where bitmasking and/or typecasting does not work as expected. I am working with an overwhelmingly big distributed system where some parts are written i C.

The few lines of code that confuses me are these:

```
uint16_t
mask(uint32_t nr)
{
  return (uint16_t)(nr & 0x1ff);
}

...

  int nr = 65536;
  int index;
  index = mask(nr);

...
```

In this case the return of mask is 65536 and not 0 as expected. There are some inconsistent type conversions in this example, but I cannot understand how the result could be wrong. We are basically masking out the lower 9 bits of an 32 bit integer and converting the result to an 16 bit integer. My best guess is that there are some compiler optimizations that changes the first 16 bits, but does nothing about the higher 16 bits since we only want to return 16 bits. Since the 'index' in this case is an 32 bit integer this also includes the 17:th bit of 'nr', which was not modified in the bitmask, thus the 17:th bit is still set to 1 and assigning 65536 to index.

Is there anyone that have an explanation of this behavior?

Edit:
I forgot some important parameters.
The prototype of the mask function is properly included. The system is built for Linux x86 with gcc 4.3.2.

Edit2:
Assembly code:

```
0805b640 <mask>:
 805b640:       55                      push   %ebp
 805b641:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 805b643:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 805b646:       65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
 805b64c:       89 45 fc                mov    %eax,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
 805b64f:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 805b651:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 805b654:       66 25 ff 01             and    $0x1ff,%ax
 805b658:       8b 55 fc                mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%edx
 805b65b:       65 33 15 14 00 00 00    xor    %gs:0x14,%edx
 805b662:       75 02                   jne    805b666 <maks+0x26>
 805b664:       c9                      leave  
 805b665:       c3                      ret    
 805b666:       e8 a5 ac 04 00          call   80a6310 <__stack_chk_fail_local>
 805b66b:       90                      nop    
 805b66c:       8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
```

Comment: [Works for me.](http://ideone.com/qljSvz) Maybe `int` is 16 bit long on your system?

Comment: Which compiler/platform etc are you using?

Comment: if you suspect this is due to optimisation you could look at the generated assembly

Comment: Make sure `mask()` is properly declared before being called, otherwise you're going to get implicit `int`, which *could* mess this up.

Comment: What are the `typedef`s for `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`? Are they provided by your compiler (i.e. how old is this compiler) or defined/overridden by your own code?

Comment: The system is compiled for linux x86 with gcc 4.3.2. There exist a prototype for mask(). uint16_t and uint32_t are provided by including linux/types.h and is not overridden by other code. I guess a have to study the assembly code.

Comment: I tested it and it is working fine. Did you declare the function in a second file? Can you paste somewhere the assembly code?

Comment: your assembly, as the one provided by David Fischer, only ANDs with the lower 16 bits. Could you also post the assembly of the calling  code (`index = mask(nr);`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what my gcc (4.6.2) produces from `mask` (with optimisations; without, there's some fluff around it):

```
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    andw    $511, %ax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

So it indeed only modifies the lower order 16 bits, and it is the responsibility of the caller to actually zero out the high-order 16 bits per

```
movzwl  %ax, %eax
```

which it does if the correct prototype is known at the call site. I very strongly suspect that

> The prototype of the mask function is properly included.

is not actually true, check and re-check. If it's true indeed, you have found a major bug (so major that we'd probably have heard about it).

> `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` are provided by including linux/types.h

Hmm, not here. They're provided by `stdint.h`. You should `#include <stdint.h>` to get them anyway, even if they're also provided by `linux/types.h` on your system, since that's the portable solution.

Comment: I`ve added the generated assembly code, it is not as elegant as yours.

Comment: but shouldn't the explicit cast to `(uint16_t)` truncate the value of `(nr & 0x1ff)` ?

Comment: @msam Well, the return type is `uint16_t`, so the compiler says it's the caller's responsibility to use only the lower order 16 bits of the register. From that standpoint, it's not necessary to clear the higher order bits. It can go wrong of course if the caller doesn't clear the unwanted bits.

Comment: so the compiler is assuming a 32-bit return when compiling the caller but then when compiling the `mask` function assumes the caller will only use the lower 16 bits since that's it return type. (i'm only following this out of interest)

Comment: @msam That's what I suspect. But if the prototype is known when compiling the caller, the caller zeros out the high order bits with my gcc, I can't really imagine that 4.3.2 would not do it too. So my money is still on the implicit `int` assumption.

Comment: Actually, when I inspected the prototypes I noticed that there was typo in the corresponding prototype. Hopefully it will work, I am currently waiting for test results.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation I see here,is that not the expected mask function is called.
Please try your example code in one file only, and/or rename the mask function. 
The bit and (nr & 0x1ff) for  your value (0x10000) should always lead to zero.